# Stop R executing System or Shell commands

Tags: r

i'd like to disable commands that can execute other non R related stuff like System(), Shell() e.g.

```
for (year in 2010:2915){
    system("calc")
}
```

from running within R.

any suggestions other than locking down the user executing?

thanks

edit: to add more context, we allow the users to create R scripts in our solution which are passed to the R Engine to execute, we then process those results.

Comment: I'm quite sure this has to be arranged at the level of the OS.  Can you specify in which context you need this?

Comment: we were looking at integrating the R engine into our solution and came up with this as being a particular vulnerability

Comment: I don't see how this is more of a "vulnerability" compared to any other computer language that can execute system commands. Which is the vast majority of them. If the solution you talk about is hosted on the server, secure the server. But without any more information on what that "solution" actually is, how users would be able to inject R code, if users should be able to inject R code, where it resides and so on, nobody will be able to give you a decent answer.

Comment: In case users should be able to interact with R over a server, take a look at RStudio Server.

Comment: interesting point, i guess it is exactly the same as if we gave users the ability to create VBScripts. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Short of editing the R source code to remove the undesirable functions, which would be tedious and probably a bit dangerous, I would override these functions:

```
# override system()
env <- as.environment("package:base")
unlockBinding("system", env) # bindings in the base R are write-protected
assign(
  "system",
  function(...){stop("This is a forbidden command!")},
  envir=env
)
lockBinding("system", env)
```

This would give the following when a user runs `system()`:

> > system()
>
> Error in system() : this is a forbidden command

So that the changes take effect each time R is started, you could override as many functions as you want this way, adding them to `.First()` in your (write-protected) ["Rprofile.site" file](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html):

```
.First <- function(){
  # code to override system() here
  # code to override shell() here
  # ...
}
```

Note that this will not prevent an ill-intentioned determined user from re-implementing the forbidden functionality though.

Comment: As an R user, i'd ditch `system()` and just use `shell()`. Or use the `.Internal()` interface to get the lower-level system function. So even if you block all interface functions like `system()` etc, you can't block `.Internal()` because then quite a lot of the base functions wouldn't work any longer. So this actually doesn't protect you at all.

Comment: I agree, Joris, this is why I have a note at the end of my answer. It may be a solution for user2983931, depending on his exact use-case. Not all users may be assumed ill-intentioned.

Comment: That's why I didn't downvote :-) Maybe you could add that this is easily surpassed by using `.Internal()` to your answer.